# Is it possible to send a view from one Activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity

I mean i have a listView and I want to send a Particular row of the listview and want to show it in another Activity with the same style of a single Item_listView.

Comment: Just Pass the details of your listview item in `Intent` by putting into `Bundle` and in your second activity create similar layout as per your row and show the details into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this:

You can just Pass the details of your `Listview` item in `Intent` by putting into `Bundle` and send in your second activity in which you create similar layout as per your Listview's row items  and show the details into it by fetching it from `Bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

let me what exactly you want to send? lview is listview  with image and one textview  passing the same image and text to another activity  whenever user clicks on view

Note:passing each list item contains image and text whenever users clicked .

```
view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                 long arg3) {
                       ListView lv = (ListView) arg0;

     String fieldname = names[arg2];// add  whatever text views you have

    TextView name=(TextView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2-lv.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.textView1);



                       ImageView img=(ImageView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2-lv.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.icon);
                       img.buildDrawingCache();
                       Bitmap bmap = img.getDrawingCache();

                       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class
                       Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                       extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", bmap);
                       i.putExtras(extras);
                       i.putExtra("text", fieldname.toString());
                     startActivity(i);
```

2nd activity:

```
imge = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagebitmap");

        imge.setImageBitmap(bmp );

        String text = extras.getString("text");

        name.setText(text);
        desc.setText(des);
```